# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Вылезает ошибка. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как исправить?

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Код строки:

```
var i = strpos(s.replace(',','.'),'.');

function check_digit(name,frac) {
    if (isNaN(frac)) frac = 0;
    if (frac <= 0) frac = -1;
    var s = $(name).val();
    var i = strpos(s.replace(',','.'),'.');
    if (i !== false && i >= 0 && i < s.length-frac-1) {
        $(name).val(s.substring(0,i+frac+1));
    }
}
```

Вот функция и в ней вылетает на реплейсе

**Обновление**

Так с этим вроде б разобрался, но теперь смотрите другая ошибка:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: pay_type is not defined

Код строки:

```
 get("req.php", {
            plugin:pay_type.value,
            type:'verify',
            account:account.value,
            language:language.value,
            jek:jek.value,
            period:period.value
        }, parse_answer);
        return true;
    }
```

`plugin:pay_type.value` ---- здесь ошибку выдает

Comment: это значит , s === undefined

Comment: s = $(name).val(); - проблема, jquery на находит блок name, соответственно val() у него === undefined

Comment: @AndyLarkin, задавайте новые вопросы, новыми темами, а не в виде комментариев к старым.